# How this data can be referenced in Ghidra?

Tags: ghidra, static-analysis, decompile, c#, game-hacking

I reverse engineered `libil2cpp.so` using ghidra. I found these lines of code in a function in the decompiler view:

```
UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs$$GetInt(*(undefined4 *)(*(int *)(Class$ItemPref + 0x5c) + 8),5,0);
```

it is apparently getting the value of a `shared_preferences`. the syntax of when getting a shared_preference in `unity` games is as follows as described in the documentation:

```
UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs.GetInt(string key, int defaultValue)
```

so as apparently the `*(undefined4 *)(*(int *)(Class$ItemPref + 0x5c) + 8)` in the reversed code is the corresponding `string key`. while in general I know where the key is in the reversed code which is at this address

```
010e94b8      undefined4      ??       ; ScoreID
```

so what I wanted to learn is that how `*(undefined4 *)(*(int *)(Class$ItemPref + 0x5c) + 8)`  is reffering to that address `010e94b8` holding the string key.

what I tried so far?

referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69652148), I double clicked the value `Class$ItemPref` in the decompiled code `*(undefined4 *)(*(int *)(Class$ItemPref + 0x5c) + 8)` and take its memory address `010dd710` and then adding `0x5c` yeilds `10DD76C` and then adding `8` yeilds `10DD774` so going to this address `10DD774` does not contain the string `ScoringID`.

also I did this taking memory address of `Class$ItemPref` which is `010dd710` and then adding `0x5c` and the multiply the size of the typecast which is `int` which is `4` then the result is `4375DB0` then adding `8` equals to `4375DB8` but this is not quite right.

but what I really wanted to learn is that how that string `ScoreID` is referred in the decompiled code `UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs$$GetInt(*(undefined4 *)(*(int *)(Class$ItemPref + 0x5c) + 8),5,0);` please help this as my limited knowledge of reversing and ghidra.

if it helps, the corresponding disassembled view of the code is as follows:

```
    003e60f0 5c 00 90 e5              ldr             r0, [r0,#0x5c]
    003e60f4 05 10 a0 e3              mov             r1, #0x5
    003e60f8 00 20 a0 e3              mov             r2, #0x0
    003e60fc 08 00 90 e5              ldr             r0, [r0,#0x8]
    003e6100 10 4c bd e8              ldmia           sp!,{r4 r10 r11 lr}
    003e6104 1a 63 14 ea              b               UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs$$GetInt                                                                        ; undefined UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs$$GetInt()
                    -- Flow Override: CALL_RETURN (CALL_TERMIN
```

Comment: I don't think the type `string` is equivalent to a `char*` where you would find the characters at the referenced memory address. Instead `string` is a struct so the pointer just leads you to that struct. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53654062/internal-structure-of-class-string-in-c (not sure if this also applies to the used `string` type in your case)